# Aggregate 2D monthly data into quarters in Google Sheets or Excel

Tags: excel, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I like would like to roll up monthly data into quarterly data

I have a 2 dimensional table as input, with each column representing a month
[monthly column](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uNK5e.png)

and would like to compute a two dimensional table with each column representing a quarter.
[quarterly column](https://i.stack.imgur.com/c9GRj.png)

Note that - as shown in the example - monthly data does not need to start or end on a quarter boundary.

I have found solutions that work if the 2 dimensional table is unpivoted but have not found solutions for pivoted data. (I'd like to unpivoting and re-pivoting if possible.)

Sample sheet here. https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1o0LBs-cXaQnaSw-GlP3qKFEf0-AMRhMy7bXviWnV4j4/edit?usp=sharing

(I have the same question for aggregating by year but I am sure that with a solution for quarters in hand years will be straightforward.)

Thanks,
Mike

I've tried various hard-coded solutions that make assumptions about the structure of the data but nothing that handles the general case yet.

Comment: Google Sheets and Excel are two different programs. Please edit your question and tags to clarify which you want.

Comment: Done. Typo. Thanks for the catch.

Answer (score 0):

Here's an approach to deal with `quarters`

***Summed by Item By Quarter***

```
=index(let(Σ,month(B8:M8),
           Δ,year(B8:M8)&" Q"&ifs(Σ<4,1,Σ<7,2,Σ<10,3,TRUE,4),
makearray(counta(A9:A),counta(O22:T22),lambda(r,c,sum(ifna(filter(filter(B9:M,A9:A=index(A9:A,r)),Δ=index(O22:T22,,c))))))))
```

***Summed by Quarter***

```
=index(let(Σ,month(B8:M8),
           Δ,year(B8:M8)&" Q"&ifs(Σ<4,1,Σ<7,2,Σ<10,3,TRUE,4),
bycol(O22:T22,lambda(z,sum(ifna(filter(B9:M,Δ=z)))))))
```

[image]